# Is this a suitable question for migration?

Tags: discussion, migration

We've got this question on Programmers:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103919/what-do-you-think-about-tecnical-support-from-ms-windows-azure

which has been flagged as off topic (which it is), but there is a comment that it might be OK here. So rather than just migrate it and hope for the best I thought I'd check with you guys first.

Comment: [Looks like they took it into their own hands.](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18805/what-is-your-opinion-on-technical-support-for-windows-azure-closed)

Comment: @John - probably as someone commented. I did try to warn them to at least check the site first and edit the post, but....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for checking in with us before migrating. It is much appreciated!

That question is too subjective for here and would be closed as such. So feel free to close it as off topic without migrating it.

Comment: Thanks - thought it would be. Do you guys hang out in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge) at all? It would be easier to contact you there.

Comment: We're not usually hanging out in there but if you put a post to [at]John Conde, [at]danlefree, and/or [at]RandomBen we'll get the notification in our inbox and check it out.

Comment: I can never remember your names! So by the time I've come here to check the about page, I think it's easier to post a question.

Comment: lol! We'll respond to you ASAP either way.